# Finding and replacing text within a file

Tags: text, awk, sed, gsub

I have a large taxonomy file that I need to edit. There is an issue with the file as "Candida" is listed as both **Candida** and **[Candida]**. What I want to do is change every case of [Candida] to Candida within the file.

I have tried doing this several ways but never get the output I am after. This is the first few lines of the taxonomy file:

```
Penicillium;marneffei;NW_002197112.1   
Penicillium;marneffei;NW_002197111.1

Penicillium;marneffei;NW_002197110.1    
Penicillium;marneffei;NW_002197109.1

Penicillium;marneffei;NW_002197108.1
```

Using sed gives me this output:

```
$ sed -i -e 's/[Candida]/Candida/g' Full_HMS_Taxonomy.txt
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197112.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197111.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197110.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197109.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197108.1
```

Using awk gives me this output:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[Candida]/,"Candida")}1' Full_HMS_Taxonomy.txt
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197112.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197111.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197110.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197109.1
PeCandidaCandidacCandidallCandidaum;mCandidarCandidaeffeCandida;NW_002197108.1
```

In both cases it is adding Candida to multiple places and multiple lines, instead of just replacing each instance of [Candida]. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[] are special characters in regexp, so you should escape them like that:

```
's/\[Candida\]/Candida/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets are treated specially by regular expression parsers, matching each character listed inside them. So, `[Candida]` matches any of the characters inside it (`C`, `a`, `n`...). That's why you get a lot of substitutions.

You need to tell those utilities that you want literal brackets by escaping them with backslashes, e.g. with sed:

```
sed -i 's/\[Candida\]/Candida/g' Full_HMS_Taxonomy.txt
```